# How to repeat a javascript function and how to reverse one

Tags: javascript

I'm a little bit ashamed to admit, that i'm not that good with javascript. I need some help.
There's a modal that opens with the help of Javascript, however i'm going to give you some code that is simplified.

imagine that there's a button somewhere in this universe
That's the modal in html and css

```
< div class="modal" > < /div >
.modal {width: 0vw;}
.modal-open {width: 50vw;}

Javascript - document.getElementById('that-button').addEventListener('click', function () {
  document.querySelector('.modal').classList.add('modal-open');
});
```

And there's another button to close it. Again - imagination is needed

```
Javascript - document.getElementById('that-other-button').addEventListener('click', function () {
  document.querySelector('.modal').classList.add('modal-close');
});

.modal-close {width: 0vw;}
```

Long story short, the modal stays hidden with width:0vw and by pressing the open button, it opens with more width. By pressing the close button, the modal closes.

However after that the modal cannot be opened again. I would like to know how.

Second issue: imagine the same scenario however without the closing button. Is it possible, to open and close the modal with the open modal button by integrating some reverse function?

I'd like to thank in advance.

With very best regards,

Anthony Ivanov

Comment: You should not be ashamed to not knowing smth

Comment: I'm going to try not to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you open it, it gains the the class `modal-open`.

When you close it, it gains the class `modal-close` so now it has **both** classes.

Clicking the open button again does nothing because it already has that class.

---

Don't use two classes to track the state of something that can be in two states.

Use one class. `add` it to open and `remove` it to close it.

---

> Is it possible, to open and close the modal with the open modal button by integrating some reverse function?

In the **general** case, no. There's no way to say "Do what this arbitrary function does but backwards". What a function does might not even be reversible.

In **this** case, you can `toggle` the class instead of adding and removing it.

Comment: Thank you, Quentin. I'm surprised how something so small can teach me so much. You did impressively good and saved me a ton of headaches!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the existence of the `modal-close` class overrides rules set by the `modal-open` class, so if it gets closed, it'll stay closed.

Rather than having two separate classes, consider using just a single one instead: have it closed by default, and then have `.modal-open` change the width. When you want to close it, don't add another class - instead, remove the existing class:

```
document.getElementById('that-other-button').addEventListener('click', function () {
  document.querySelector('.modal').classList.remove('modal-open');
});
```

Comment: You have no clue how much i needed this. Thank you!